# Search in 3 lists of lists

Tags: python, gitlab-api

I have 3 lists

```
user_list = ['Administrator', 'Deepak', 'Bhamar','Akash', 'Harshit']

group_members = [['Harshit', 'randam value', 40], ['Harshit', 'randam value', 40], ['Rohit', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Akash', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Akash', 'randam value', 40], ['Harshit', 'randam value', 40]]

project_members = [['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Rakesh', 'random value', 30], ['Priyanka', 'random value', 30], ['Sapna', 'random value', 40], ['Amit', 'random value', 40]]
```

Now, i want to search the names in list "user_list" on "project_members" & "group_members" and return the corresponding values. Those lists are taken from gitlab through apis and i'm trying to get users projects and groups details and i'm totally new to python.

i can't get the logic to achieve this.

expected output in json:

```
    Administrator:{
           project:
               []
           groups:{
               [['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Rakesh', 'random value', 30]
    Bhamar:{
      projects:
           [['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40],['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40],['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40]]
     groups:
          []
```

code:

```
import gitlab
import csv
import os
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('git.gltlab.com', private_token='private_token')

with open("group.csv",'w+') as f:
    pass
with open("project.csv",'w+') as f:
    pass

group_list = []
project_list = []
group_members = []
project_members = []
user_list = []


def logging(file,data):
    with open(os.path.join(file+".csv"),'a') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(data)


def main():
    for page_no in range(1,4):
        groups = gl.groups.list(per_page=5,page=page_no)
        for id in groups:
           group_list.append(id.name)

        projects = gl.projects.list(per_page=9,page=page_no)
        for project in projects:
            project_list.append(project.id)


        users = gl.users.list(per_page=1,page=page_no)
        for user in users:
           user_list.append(user)

    get_group_members()
    get_project_members()


def get_group_members():
    for group in group_list:
        group_1 = gl.groups.get(group)
        grp_members = group_1.members.list()
        for name in grp_members:
            data = [str(name.name),str(group),name.access_level]
            logging(file="group",data=data)
            group_members.append(data)


def get_project_members():
    for project in project_list:
        project_1 = gl.projects.get(project)
        prjt_memebrs = project_1.members.list()
        for name in prjt_memebrs:
            test = [str(name.name),str(project_1.name_with_namespace),name.access_level]
            logging(file="project",data=test)
            project_members.append(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be able to produce the json you require.

```
import json 

user_list = ['Administrator', 'Deepak', 'Bhamar','Akash', 'Harshit']

group_members = [['Harshit', 'randam value', 40], ['Harshit', 'randam value', 40], ['Rohit', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Akash', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Bhamar', 'randam value', 40], ['Akash', 'randam value', 40], ['Harshit', 'randam value', 40]]

project_members = [['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Administrator', 'random value', 50], ['Rakesh', 'random value', 30], ['Priyanka', 'random value', 30], ['Sapna', 'random value', 40], ['Amit', 'random value', 40]]

data = {}

for user in user_list:
    data[user] = {}
    data[user]["groups"] = []
    for group in group_members:
        if user in group:
            data[user]["groups"].append(group)
    data[user]["project"] = []
    for project in project_members:
        if user in project:
            data[user]["project"].append(project)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

It loops through the lists, and creates a dictionary whose keys are the user, and whose values are a further dictionary. The nested dictionary has keys groups and projects, whose values are the lists other the users involvement.